# Plus Multiply | December Long Challenge Division 2

Tags: java, data-structures

The first line of the input contains a single integer T denoting the number of test cases. The description of T test cases follows.
The first line of each test case contains a single integer N.
The second line contains N space-separated integers A1,A2,…,AN.
Output
For each test case, print a single line containing one integer ― the desired number of pairs.

```
Example Input
2
3
2 4 2
3
0 2 3
Example Output
1
0
```

My solution looks like:

```
class Codechef {
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    ArrayList<Integer> resultList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int T;

    T = scanner.nextInt();

    for(int i = 0;  i < T; i++) {
        int N;
        N = scanner.nextInt();
        int A[] = new int[N];

        for(int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            A[j] = scanner.nextInt();
        }

        quick_sort(A, 0, N-1);

        int pos = 0, pairs = 0;
        while(pos < A.length - 1) {
            if(A[pos] == A[pos + 1]) {
                pos += 2;
                pairs += 1;
            } else {
                ++pos;
            }
        }

        resultList.add(pairs);
    }
    for(int pairCount : resultList) {
        System.out.println(pairCount);
    }
    scanner.close();
}    
}
```

It successfully runs the example test cases but fails on submission, My question is, if the input is something like 1 1 2 2 1, then what should be the answer, 3? as there are 2 pairs of 1, and 1 of 2's.

Also, what will be the suggested data structure to be used for this purpose, Java with primitive data types is taking too much longer to execute it with 40,000 input values. What's wrong with my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question, I'd say yes that each pair of 1's would count separately so you'd get 3.

I think your code is failing since you're only counting touching pairs after you sort.
For example,
1 1 1, you find the first pair at index 0/1, but then advance pos += 2.This means you're missing the two other pairs of 1's.

Your solution seems to be O(nlogn) because of sorting but I can think of a O(n) solution.

```
int[] backing = new int [10];
for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
    int x = scanner.nextInt();
    backing[x]++;
}
//At this point, you have a backing array with the frequency of each integer
```

You'll want something similar to [this](https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/discretemathematics/combinations.php) to calculate the number of pairs. It's the frequency of each integer choose 2, since you want to choose each occurrence of a pair.

So for example if you know you have 5 1's, then you'll compute:
5!/(2!*3!) = 10